# Call a function instead of intent in android tabactivity

Tags: android, function, android-intent, tabactivity

Sorry for my bad english...

i made a tab bar activity in android application with this code:

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page2.class);
TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId); 

View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(labelId);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

With this code i can create any tab i want and all tabs call an activity. All works fine, but there is a way to call a function when click (or tap) on a tab instead of call an activity?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  a onclick listener for Tabhost

you will have 3 ids initialize them and use onclick for the tab you want

```
    Tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                         yourfunctionname(); //call your functions 

        }
    });
```